# Make vertical scrollbar always visible in the Xcode source editor

Tags: xcode

I want to make the vertical scrollbar (and the red lines representing errors) always visible, not just when scrolling.

[image: vertical scrollbar in the source editor]

I know that there is a system-wide setting in macOS to make all scrollbars always visible, but I'd rather keep the current system setting on (automatically detected).